# Get Video URL From Firebase Database into videoView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-videoview

I'm doing a video app like Instagram. I have successfully finished everything including video upload except playing the different videos that users had uploaded.

I got some code here that enables me play video from a given URL on firebase into `VideoView` and it works, however it plays the same video everywhere.

How can I make it play specific videos that users had uploaded

**XML**

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/post_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:clickable="true" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
        String str = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lol-videos-8dc74.appspot.com/o/Blog_Images%2Fvideo%3A10142?alt=media&token=9f7734fa-f714-4838-bd65-8a4d594ec2ce";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);

 public void setImage(String video){
        VideoView post_image = (VideoView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        post_image.setVideoURI(uri);
        post_image.requestFocus();
        post_image.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be certain that the video in Storage is actually in a format that Android devices can play.  VideoView cannot play everything - only the [types of videos that Android supports](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html).

What you're doing now by passing the uri directly into the VideoView is interpreted as an attempt to stream the video from the given uri.  Firebase Storage doesn't support video streaming, so that's won't work.  Streaming from a uri requires that the server on the other end be able to stream the given resource.

If want to play a video from Storage, you'll have to download *entirety* first, saved to a local file, then point the VideoView at the local file for playback.

With Audio it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you can actually record video and send it to Firebase then play the specific video. If you want you can even put them into RecyclerView

**XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="record"
        android:text="Record"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="upload"
        android:text="Upload"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="download"
        android:text="Download"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import android.text.TextUtils;

import java.io.File;

public class RecorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Uri videoUri;
    private EditText mPostTitle;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE =101;
    private StorageReference videoRef;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recor);

        mPostTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleField);


        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserVideos").child("videos" + uid);


        StorageReference storageRef =
                FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        videoRef = storageRef.child("/videos/" + uid + "userIntro.3gp");

    }

    public void upload(View view){
        if (videoUri != null){
            UploadTask uploadTask = videoRef.putFile(videoUri);





            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(RecorActivity.this,
                            "Upload Failed: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }).addOnSuccessListener(



                    new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {



                            Uri downloadurl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                            newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                            newPost.child("video").setValue(downloadurl.toString());

                            Toast.makeText(RecorActivity.this, "Video successfuly sent!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            //checking if the value is provided
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val)) {

                                mPostTitle.setText("");


                            } else {
                                //if the value is not given displaying a toast

                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnProgressListener(
                    new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            updateProgress(taskSnapshot);
                        }
                    });


        }else {
            Toast.makeText(RecorActivity.this, "Nothing to upload",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void updateProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot){

        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") long fileSize =
                taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();


        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
        long uploadBytes = taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();

        long progress =(100 * uploadBytes) / fileSize;

        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbar);
        progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
    }



    public void record(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    public void download(View view){

        try{
            final File localFile = File.createTempFile("userIntro", "3gp");

            videoRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess
                                (FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(RecorActivity.this, "Playing....",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            final VideoView videoView=
                                    (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
                            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(localFile));
                            videoView.start();

                        }

                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener(){
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(RecorActivity.this,
                            "Download Failed:" + e.getLocalizedMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(RecorActivity.this,
                    "Failed to create temp  file;" + e.getLocalizedMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {
        videoUri = data.getData();
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Video Saved to:\n" +
                        videoUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else if (requestCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Video recording Cancelled.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to record Video",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```